# JSON object not found in JSON array

Tags: java, json

I am aware there are duplicate questions. I am not able to figure this out despite that.

Below is a JSON file which I receive from an API. I need to get the "year" value.

The error I am getting is:

> message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[1] not found.

Which relates to the line on Java:

```
JSONObject year = years.getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("years");
```

I also tried:

```
JSONObject year = years.getJSONObject(1);
```

Why is this code not working? Isn't `index 1` clearly `year` in the `years` array?

JSON

```
{
    "make": {
        "id": 200000404,
        "name": "Chevrolet",
        "niceName": "chevrolet"
    },
    "model": {
        "id": "Chevrolet_Camaro",
        "name": "Camaro",
        "niceName": "camaro"
    },
    "drivenWheels": "rear wheel drive",
    "numOfDoors": "2",
    "options": [],
    "colors": [],
    "manufacturerCode": "1EH67",
    "price": {
        "baseMSRP": 34180.0,
        "baseInvoice": 32813.0,
        "deliveryCharges": 900.0,
        "usedTmvRetail": 17766.0,
        "usedPrivateParty": 16321.0,
        "usedTradeIn": 14755.0,
        "estimateTmv": false,
        "tmvRecommendedRating": 0
    },
    "categories": {
        "market": "Performance",
        "EPAClass": "Compact Cars",
        "vehicleSize": "Midsize",
        "primaryBodyType": "Car",
        "vehicleStyle": "Convertible",
        "vehicleType": "Car"
    },
    "vin": "2G1FC3D33C9165616",
    "squishVin": "2G1FC3D3C9",
    "years": [{
        "id": 100531911,
        "year": 2012,
        "styles": [{
            "id": 101395591,
            "name": "LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)",
            "submodel": {
                "body": "Convertible",
                "modelName": "Camaro Convertible",
                "niceName": "convertible"
            },
            "trim": "LT"
        }]
    }],
    "matchingType": "SQUISHVIN",
    "MPG": {
        "highway": "28",
        "city": "17"
    }
}
```

JAVA

```
    public String vehicleData(@PathParam("vin") String vin,
                               @PathParam("key") String key) throws Exception {

        GetVehicleJSON jsonData = new GetVehicleJSON(vin, key);
        JSONObject data = jsonData.getVehicleData();

        String name = data.getJSONObject("make").getString("name"); 

        String highway = data.getJSONObject("MPG").getString("highway");
        String city = data.getJSONObject("MPG").getString("city");

        JSONArray years = data.getJSONArray("years");
        JSONObject year = years.getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("years");
        String s = year.getString("year");

        return name + " " + s + " " + highway + " " + city;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, 1 points to the second element in the array, which doesn't exist in this case. 0 points to the first JSONObject, which contains year. So you want `years.getJSONObject(0)`.

Comment: Try `JSONObject year = years.getJSONObject(0);`. Array indexing generally starts at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski isn't the "id" object at the 0 index?

Comment: @NutellaAddict. `years` is a `JSONArray` which is an array containing `JSONObjects`. In your example, this `JSONArray`, `[ ]`, contains one `JSONObject`, `{ .. }`. Within this one object you have, `id`, `year`, etc. So  it is `JSONArray -> JSONObject -> year`.

Comment: @NutellaAddict No. `"years"` refers to an Array (`[...]`) holding a single Object (`{"id":...}`). The `0` index of the Array will give you that Object. Then, from that, you can retrieve the `"year"` as a String.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski  Ah I see, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json shows that the years value is an array with 1 element and inside that element is an object:

```
"years": [{ "id": 100531911, "year": 2012, "styles": [{ "id": 101395591, "name": "LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)", "submodel": { "body": "Convertible", "modelName": "Camaro Convertible", "niceName": "convertible" }, "trim": "LT" }] }],
```

Because array element numbering begins at 0, that means if you select element 1 you will get this error:

> message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[1] not found.

To fix it you need to select element 0 instead of 1:

```
years.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're working with JSON array whose indexing is zero-based. Do it as:

```
   JSONArray years = data.getJSONArray("years");

   String year = years.getJSONObject(0).getString("year");
```